# Postgres Database not getting migrated in Kubernetes pods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, kubernetes, database-migration

I'm trying to deploy my RoR application on Kubernetes. I'm using PostgreSQL as the database. I'm deploying both the front-end and back-end separately and I'm using configmap to inject the environment variables. However, I'm noticing a strange behaviour. Sometimes, the database is getting migrated and sometimes it isn't. Sometimes, the app works fine whereas sometimes the database isn't getting migrated. I really can't figure out what's the issue.  The logs also says you have 1 pending migration.

Here's my `Dockerfile` for the fron-end:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  curl vim wget \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev &&\
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
  curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

COPY . .
RUN bundle install &&\ 
  gem install rails 
ENTRYPOINT ["bash" , "commands.sh"]
```

here's `commands.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle install
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
rails db:migrate
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

I'm using postrSQL latest image for my database.
Can someone help me figure out what's happening?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing actual logs. Nothing useful in the container output in any of the two situations?

Comment: Nope. I only got one pending migration error in the application container. Although i managed to eradicate the error by modifying the dockerfile and instead of creating the database and migrating it i ended up reloading the schema then seeding and then migrating it.